# Range checking compilation difficulties in Java

Tags: compiler-errors, range, expression

I'm trying to assemble a simple Range check for a Net Pay calculator and can't compile this range check, I keep changing it and this is the iteration with the fewest errors:

```
 grossPay = houRate * hoursWorked;
                    final double LOW_LIM = 300.01;
                    final double LOW_RATE = 0.08;
                    final double MEDIUM_LIM = 400;
                    final double MEDIUM_RATE = 0.10;
                    final double AVEARGE_LIM = 500;
                    final double AVEARGE_RATE = 0.12;
                    final double HIGH_LIM = 500.01;
                    final double HIGH_RATE = 0.15;

                    if(grossPay <= LOW_LIM)
                       taxRate = LOW_RATE;
                    else if(grossPay >= MEDIUM_LIM + && + grossPay < AVEARGE_LIM)
                       taxRate = MED_RATE; 
                    else if(grossPay >= AVEARGE_LIM + && + grossPay < HIGH_LIM)
                       taxRate = AVEARGE_RATE;
                    else if(grossPay >= HIGH_LIM)
                       taxRate = HIGH_RATE;
                 taxHeld = taxRate * grossPay;
```

let me know if I am too vague and I will include the rest of the code (that part worked before I added this range check).

Comment: This was the range check I tried first:     if (grossPay < 300.01) {  taxRate = .08;     }
                        else if (grossPay < 400.01 && grossPay > 300.00)
                           {
                           taxRate = .10;
                           }
                        else if (grossPay < 500.01 && grossPay > 400.00)
                           {
                           taxRate = .12;
                           }
                        else if (grossPay > 500.00)
                           {
                           taxRate = .15;
                           }

Comment: `if(grossPay >= MEDIUM_LIM + && + grossPay < AVEARGE_LIM)` - what do you understand that syntax to mean?

Comment: What error messages is the compiler giving?

Comment: illegal start of expression for:     else if(grossPay >= MEDIUM_LIM + && + grossPay < AVEARGE_LIM)      and:     else if(grossPay >= AVEARGE_LIM + && + grossPay < HIGH_LIM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there are extra operators in the middle two lines of the test. Replace "`+ && +`" with just "`&&`" and that should eliminate the syntax error.

Comment: That worked for those errors but now it thinks I didn't initiate the taxRate variable.  I did declare it in the beginning of my code as double taxRate in the original method body.  Because it is not a scanner variable, I didn't put in Scanner tax = new Scanner(System.in).  any ideas?

Comment: That's probably due to the lack of a plain `else` clause in the `if-then-else` construct. Due to the way the constants are it always executes one of the `then` clauses, but the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that. Either change the last one from `else if(grosspay >= HIGH_LIM)` to just `else`, or initialize `taxRate` to something when you declare it.

Comment: Amazing!  I thought that I had to explicitly state the HIGH_LIM to get a result.  Well It compiles.  Ltime to logic test.  Todd you rock!